# How to count each exception by itself

Tags: python-3.x, exception, counter

I have currently been working where I create my own exception etc:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

"""
exceptions
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This module contains the set of multiple exceptions.
"""


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #


class RequestsException(Exception):
    """
    Base exception class
    """


class TooManyFailedRequests(RequestsException):
    """
    Raise an exception for FailedRequests
    """


class TooManyTimedOut(RequestsException):
    """
    Raise an exception for TimedOut
    """
```

and I have created a script that has a counter:

```
import time

import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, ReadTimeout, Timeout

from lib.exceptions import (
    TooManyFailedRequests,
    TooManyTimedOut
)


def send_notification(msg):
    print(f"Sending notification to discord later on! {msg}")


class simpleExceptionWay:
    """
    Counter to check if we get exceptions x times in a row.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.failedCnt = 0

    def check(self, exception, msg):
        self.failedCnt += 1
        if self.failedCnt > 2:
            send_notification(msg)
            raise exception(msg)

    def reset(self):
        self.failedCnt = 0


# Call this function where we want to check
# simpleException.check(exception, msg)
simpleException = simpleExceptionWay()


def test():
    """
    We also want to count in here if we ever reach in here.
    """

    return "Hello world"


def setup_scraper(site_url):
    session = requests.session()

    while True:

        try:
            response = session.post(site_url, timeout=5)

            if response.ok:
                simpleException.reset()
                exit()

            if response.status_code in {429, 403, 405}:
                print(f"Status -> {response.status_code}")

                simpleException.check(
                    TooManyFailedRequests,
                    {
                        'Title': f'Too many {response.status_code} requests in a row',
                        'Reason': str(),
                        'URL': str(site_url),
                        'Proxies': str(
                            session.proxies
                            if session.proxies
                            else "No proxies used"
                        ),
                        'Headers': str(session.headers),
                        'Cookies': str(session.cookies)
                    }
                )

                time.sleep(3)
                continue

        except (ReadTimeout, Timeout, ConnectionError) as err:

            simpleException.check(
                TooManyTimedOut,
                {
                    'Title': f'Timed out',
                    'Reason': "Too many timed out",
                    'URL': str(site_url),
                    'Proxies': str(
                        session.proxies
                        if session.proxies
                        else "No proxies used"
                    ),
                    'Headers': str(session.headers),
                    'Cookies': str(session.cookies)
                }
            )
            continue


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup_scraper("https://www.google.se/")
```

My problem currently is that I only have 1 counter that counts all together and I wonder how can I do for example if we reach `TooManyTimedOut` 100 times in a row, then we want to raise and when we reach `TooManyFailedRequests` 5 times in a row then we should raise exception. Is that possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the type() function to get the type of the exception and then use the **name** property of that type to get it's name as a string. Then you can store this in a dictionary that will keep track of exception count.

```py
class simpleExceptionWay:
    """
    Counter to check if we get exceptions x times in a row.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.exception_count = {}

    def check(self, exception, msg):
        exception_name = exception.__name__

        # the dict.get() method will return the value from a dict if exists, else it will return the value provided
        self.exception_count[exception_name] = self.exception_count.get(exception_name, 0) + 1
          
        if self.exception_count[exception_name] > 2:
            send_notification(msg)
            raise exception(msg)

    def reset(self):
        self.exception_count.clear()
```

Comment: Hmm right, but for example if I want a specific type to trigger the raise exception if we reach 100 for example? How do we do that? For now it seems that every exception we do now it will trigger after second loop? - Also im not quite sure how `exception_name = type(exception).__name__` would return the name, seems like it just returns the name "type" for me

Comment: If you wanna check for specific exceptions you can use `if self.exception_count["TooManyTimedOut"] == 100`, and as for the __name__, it should work.

Comment: Oh that is true, what about the `type(exception).__name__` - that looks like its returning just the word "type" for me ```>>> print(self.exception_count, exception_name) >>> {'type': 1} type ```

Comment: Try doing this: `int.__name__` and you'll get a string, if you have a variable that's holding an object reference you can use `type(myvar)` to get the type and then use `__name__` to get the class name as a string. `a = {"b": 20}; print(type(a).__name__)`

Comment: Oh and, since you are using `check(exception, msg)` you could make an another parameter `allowed_count` or something similar then you can use it in the if statement to make your code smaller: `if self.exception_count[exception_name] >= allowed_count:`

Comment: the ```a = {"b": 20}; print(type(a).__name__)``` returns for me `dict` - Is it how it supposed to do? I thought it would print out the a ? but I could misunderstand of course :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if I add the ```allowed_count_timedout == 100``` in the init or should I add it as parameter instead?

Comment: Yeah that's what it's expected to do. Basically, a dictionary is a class called `dict` so when we did type(a) we got the `dict` class, then we used `__name__` and got `dict` as a string

Comment: How you go about detecting exception count is up to you. I would do it as a parameter but do how you think it's best.

Comment: But hmm, but if the name is dict then, how would it know the difference between TimedOut and TooManyFailed? Will it still do it? I cant still get the logic in my head since its new for me and super interesting - My guess is that we should remove the word type() inside the check(). to get the actual name?

Comment: Oh I was just giving an example of using `type()` and `__name__`
Also I've noticed to fail that you're passing the class as a parameter to the check function
In that case, we don't need type() at all, you can just use `exception.__name__`. I edited my answer so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230841/discussion-between--and-protractornewbie).

Comment: Ahh there we go! Yeah that make sense now :D Because yeah haha :P